# AngularJS - Omitting user from an unordered list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make a list of users on a chat page using Angular.JS. I want to have the user see his own name at the top of the list. I would like to accomplish this by either:

A) Omitting the user's own name from the list and then printing the user's name elsewhere.
OR
B) Pushing the user's name to the top of an unordered list (you see your own name at the top of the list.)

Here's the relevant code:

***ChatCtrl.js***

```
function ($scope, $log, socket, personService) {
   // ..........
        $scope.person = personService.getPerson();

    // personService is a service which gather info each time a person logs in

        socket.emit('people-join-server', {
            user: $scope.person.name,
            interests: $scope.person.interests
        });     


        socket.on("update-people", function(data) {

            $scope.people = data.people;
            $scope.count = data.count;              
            $scope.$digest();
        });
  // ..........
    }
```

***Socket.js***

```
var _ = require('underscore')._;

// the io argument comes from the root app.js file
module.exports = function (io) {
    var people = {};
    var sockets = [];
    var sizePeople = _.size(people);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

        socket.on('people-join-server', function (data) {
            people[socket.id] = {"user": data.user, "interests": data.interests};

            io.sockets.emit('update-people', {people: people, count: sizePeople});
        });
    // ........
    }
};
```

***chat_page.html***

```
 <ul>               
    <li ng-repeat="peeps in people">
        <span>{{peeps.user}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put ng-show on the li tag itself :

```
    <ul>
        {{person.name}}
        <li ng-repeat="peeps in people" ng-show="peeps.user!=person.name">
            <span>{{peeps.user}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This perhaps will eliminate the empty space issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I've almost got the answer, you would manipulate the chat_page.html file by adding an ng-show condition to the span element enclosing {{peeps.user}}, like so:

```
        <ul>
            {{person.name}}
            <li ng-repeat="peeps in people">
                <span ng-show="peeps.user!=person.name">{{peeps.user}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

As you can see, I have the user's own name on top using the {{person.name}} variable, then the rest of the names printed out with the {{peeps.user}} variable.

The only issue I have now is there's a empty space where my name once was, so a list item is now printed but not the user's name.